# How to suspend next run of Oracle Job?

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, dbms-job

I have a job which is scheduled to run at a specified time daily. How do I stop it from running from its next schedule only? It should then run as usual in successive schedules.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using the `dbms_job` package rather than the more recent `dbms_scheduler` package, you can just call [`next_date`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_job.htm#i1000769)

```
begin
  dbms_job.next_date( <<your job number from dba_jobs>>,
                      <<the date you want it to run next>> );
  commit;
end;
```